# Not all google logins should be equal on my phone

Tags: android-device-manager

While setting up a new phone for a family member whose location I want to track and calendar to manage (yeah, Big Brother type for medical reasons), I logged from my phone to her google account as an additional account. So in most google apps and sites I have this dropdown like who am I currently using this service as - e.g. posting calendar meetings and events as her, which may be shared to other family members who'd be available to help at a particular time slot.

Unfortunately, in google find me (location and stolen device protection app) it works both ways - if she (or someone else) logs in as her account on her phone, there are options to e.g. remotely lock or wipe my phone - as it is logged into google. Which would be unfortunate.

Is there some way to avoid this and tell at least this particular app that only my account is almighty here? (I know security was revamped a lot in Android 8, but our phones range in Android 4 to 6)

Comment: Unfortunately this is impossible. All accounts that are added to your to the phone are now able to track and erase your phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to deactivate google-s " find device"  device manager from settings(usually in the security tab)...but this will also block you to reset it remotely..

Comment: Thanks. While sub-optimal,  it is actually a viable option for me, since I can have an equivalent feature (Remote find and wipe) for my phone from its vendor, so doing it via Google was the backup plan.